# Beard trimmer powered by LiPo battery

Tags: dc-motor, lipo

I'm trying to convert a beard trimmer's motor to run on LiPo battery instead of original Ni-Mh AAA size battery.
It occurred to me as simple DIY project, but it turns out that's not the case.

**Background**
The trimmer is a regular Philips trimmer with a simple circuit inside.
There is a DC motor connected to a switch and a rechargeable AAA size Ni-Mh 1.2V battery. It takes around 8 hours to charge the battery and then around 30 minutes of usage time.

**What I did**
I removed the Ni-Mh battery and connected the 300mAh 3.7V at 1A. The motor only spins a few times when the circuit completes and stops immediately. Why would that happen? The voltage and amps are more than what Ni-Mh can supply, so why doesn't it run the DC motor?

Comment: Abusing equipment with more than twice the designed voltage is a fundamentally bad idea.  The existing motor and or circuitry (many of these are an electronic toggle) is designed for the nominal voltage of the original cell, not the more than 2x higher nominal voltage of the replacement.  If you want a trimmer that runs on a lithium battery, buy one.

Comment: If it stopped turning you are not measuring your voltage and probably shorted out your LiPo cell. Stall Motor current is 10x that at rated RPM and rated voltage

Comment: @ChrisStratton Buying is always the option. It's the tinkering that is more fun.
The motor is not being abused. It is rated to work at 3.7V and 1A.

Comment: No, it's not.  According to your post is is designed for an AAA battery.

Comment: The bottom line is that matching motor supply must have an impedance <<< than the motor start impedance which is the DC resistance of the coil. This is not the case with a higher voltage low capacity LiPo pack compared to the NiMH 1.2V pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overstressed your battery.

300mAh 3.7V at 1A is 3C and the battery is only rated for 1C

Meanwhile the NiMH [duracell](https://d2ei442zrkqy2u.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DX2400H-850mAh-AAA-Technical-Datasheet-March-20161.pdf) is rated for 850mAh at 0.1C or 10 hour discharge and if you are only getting 0.5h life then the capacity is probably reduced to 60% of 850mAh or say 500mAh or 1A in 0.5h load but meanwhile the Motor if drawing 1A @1.2V has Req=1.2 Ohms has a DCR 10% this or 0.12 Ohms which would shunt the 300mA LiPo pack to <<1V and quickly drop << 0.5V  and stall motor and heat up the battery pack.

This means the DCR of your cheap 300mA LiPo pack must be around 500 mOhms, wheras a good 2600mAh 18650 cell is < 50 mOhms.

### conclusion

The fact that Duracell specs are only 0.1C to 0.5C should tell you using an estimated  3C loading (1A/300mAh=3.3C)  is a bad idea.

( 0.1C = 10h load for rated mAh  e.g. not<=0.5h which is why you got 1 second or so)

Although an over simplification and there are several fudge factors, your battery DC series resistance  must produce a start current (I=V/DCR) of about <10% of the momentary short cicuit current of the battery in order to have good performance.

Comment: who is the troll (-1)

Comment: Why does the community have negative vibes?
Why is my question downvoted?
I asked a question which is not asked before (I search well)?
And even if I'm abusing equipment, I want to learn, what is wrong in that?

Comment: -1 vibes from many users who have experience but cant express tehcnical info without being personal, or -1 with no comments, I call trolls as they add no useful information  , they ought to feel shame for not asking why or how about , or add useful intelligence > I think it is just immaturity.  But you question actually has been asked in different ways many times.

Answer (score 0):

Also to add to Chris's answer, LiPo batteries are extremely particular to how they are charged. They are very prone to exploding when not charged with a charger specific to LiPo batteries. So without removing the original charge circuit and adding a LiPo charge circuit you are subjecting yourself to exploding batteries and possibly chemical burns.

Comment: 300mAh pack would get hot but has to reach burning hot cell temps to pass the thermal runaway condition, which for experimentation and learning is not going to explode but with est. 10 watts get hot fairly quickly  (300mAH*3.7V~1Wh ) THis risk rises as capacity and density increases

Comment: On the upside, just use a Note 7  battery and delete all that motor and blade stuff. Get a single (or was that singe-le) lifetime beard trim.